# If, Then Statement to let User Know Command Could Not execute?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Lets just say we have this as Command1

```
Dim Command1 = "whoami.exe >> C:\Hello.Txt"
```

The program will read a list of users from a text file and then perform the action on each of them. If the user does not exist, or they are part of a password protected computer, I would like to see that in my printout.

I have this but am Unsure how to write the If Then Statement (If that is the ebst route to take)

```
For Each strUserName as String in strLines
Shell("cmd.exe /c" & Command1)
If Command1 = fail??
Then msgbox("Oops") ???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to redirect the output of 'whoami.exe' to your own console, you can do the following:

```
Dim startInfo As New ProcessStartInfo()
startInfo.Arguments = "c:\Hello.txt"
startInfo.FileName = "c:\whoami.exe"
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
startInfo.UseShellExecute = False

Using process As Process = Process.Start(startInfo)
    Using stream As StreamReader = process.StandardOutput
        Console.Write(stream.ReadToEnd())
    End Using
End Using
```

You will need to import the System.Diagnostics namespace. If 'whoami.exe' returns an exit code you can use, you can also use the Process class to check it by calling:

```
process.WaitForExit()
Dim code As Integer = process.ExitCode
If code = 1 Then
    ' success
Else
    ' other
End If
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the `If Then` statement in either one line or multiple lines ending with an `End If`

```
If Command1 = fail Then msgbox("Oops")
```

or

```
If Command1 = fail Then 
    msgbox("Oops")
End If
```

Here is the msdn documentation for the [if statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs.aspx).